# passing argument to map function

Tags: javascript

I have code like:

```
var addX = (e) => return e+1;
```

I am calling like:

```
[1,2,3].map(addX);
```

Can I make "1" dynamic? Like:

```
[1,2,3].map(addX(2)); //this wont work, in this case it should add 2
```

Comment: You are missing bracket 1,2,3].map(addX(2)); //this wont work

Comment: This might help - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a closure over `e` and return a function with one parameter for the callback.

```js
var addX = x => v => x + v;

console.log([1, 2, 3].map(addX(2)));
```

Comment: For the reduce method, I am using like `var test = (accumulation, task) => ` , so with the closured version should be `var test = e => v =>  (accumulation, task) =>` ?

Comment: no, v is the value of the array, you need `test = constant => (acc, task) => acc + task + constant` (if that is the function, you want).

Answer (score 2):

You can use currying like this:

```js
var addX = n => e => e + n;
console.log([1,2,3].map(addX(2)));
console.log([1,2,3].map(addX(10)));
```

What this does is, you pass the number (`n`) that you want to be added to the function and it returns a new function which adds that number to it's argument (`e`) (each element when using map)

Comment: I was trying to write this answer but this new syntax is so god awful I couldn't get it right.

Comment: I don't think this is called `currying`. :)

Comment: I also find the new syntax quite hard to read at a glance, which makes me think it's not very good, the answer is fine though

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`bind(thisArg, argument1)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to send an extra parameter

```js
  var addX = (a, b) => a+b;
  console.log("2", [1,2,3].map(addX.bind(Array, 2)))
  console.log("5", [1,2,3].map(addX.bind(Array, 5)))
```

The this argument really does not matter in this case. I just put Array there, it can be this, null, etc.

Comment: @NinaScholz lol, I basically wrote that as you made the comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function to return a function that takes your add amount.

Here is an example below.

```js
var addX = (addbit) => (e) => e + addbit;

console.log([1,2,3].map(addX(2)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `closure` for that:

```js
var addX = inc => e => e + inc;

var res = [1,2,3].map(addX(2));

console.log(res);
```

**EXPLANATION**

```
var addX = inc => e => e + inc;
```

Is the equivalent of:

```
var addX = function(inc) {
    return function(e) {
        return e + inc;
    }
}
```

So `addX(2)` returns the callback `function(e) { return e + 2 }` and it's the callback used by `array.map`

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this :)

```
var addX = (e) =>   e+1;

[1,2,3].map(num => addX(num))
```

Answer (score 0):

Several utility libraries like Lodash, Underscore, and Ramda provide a `curry()` utility function that takes a function and returns a new version of that function that can take the same arguments one at a time, a few at a time, or all at once.

This means that you can create an `add` function that can either add two numbers right away `add(4, 5)` or that can "pre-bake" a function with one of the values included: `const increment = add(1); console.log(increment(5));`

```js
const add = _.curry((x, y) => x + y);

console.log(add(6, 7));

console.log([1,2,3].map(add(10)));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

If you don't want to include a whole library just for this purpose, you can also use this standalone version of `curry`:

```js
var curryN = (function () {
    var slice = Function.prototype.call.bind(Array.prototype.slice);
    var bindArr = function (f, arr) { return f.bind.apply(f, [{}].concat(arr)); };

    return function curryN(argCount, func) {
        return function fn() {
            var args = slice(arguments, 0, argCount);

            return args.length === argCount
                ? func.apply({}, args)
                : bindArr(fn, args);
        };
    };
})();

var curry = function curry(func) { return curryN(func.length, func); };

const add = curry((x, y) => x + y);

console.log(add(6, 7));

console.log([1,2,3].map(add(10)));
```